# YCM could not work after build

Tags: compiling, gcc, vim

YCM didn't work after build finish, although .vimrc is being set.

What did I do?

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
sudo apt-get install clang
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
git clone https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git
git submodule update --init --recursive
./install.py --clang-completer --system-libclang
cp third_party/ycmd/examples/.ycm_extra_conf.py  ~
cd ..  
cd..
cd..
vim .vimrc
```

Here I added to .vimrc:

```
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.ycm_extra_conf.py
```

Then:

```
vim  test.c
```

But code complete function did not work!

#### Outputs

`vim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Included patches: 1-1689
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +terminfo
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +textobjects
+channel         +gettext         -mzscheme        +timers
+cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clientserver    +iconv           +packages        -toolbar
-clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +job             -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xsmp
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax
```

`:YcmDebugInfo`:

```
E492: Not an editor command: YcmDebugInfo
```

OS version, distribution, etc.:

```
Linux ubuntu 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Installation commands:

```
./install.py --clang-completer --system-libclang
```

`clang --version`:

```
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

ycm build log:

```
Searching Python 2.7 libraries...
Found Python library: /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
Found Python headers folder: /usr/include/python2.7
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.6") 
Using libclang to provide semantic completion for C/C++/ObjC
Using external libclang: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.8.so.1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/ycm_build_uuTb3r
Scanning dependencies of target BoostParts
[  1%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/errors.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/long.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/str.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object_protocol.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/slice.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/dict.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/converter/from_python.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/converter/arg_to_python_base.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/converter/registry.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/converter/type_id.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/list.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/tuple.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object_operators.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/import.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/exec.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/wrapper.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/module.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/function_doc_signature.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/enum.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/stl_iterator.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/pickle_support.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/inheritance.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/function.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/life_support.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/class.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/iterator.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/w32_regex_traits.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/wide_posix_api.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/regex_raw_buffer.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/instances.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/wc_regex_traits.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/winstances.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/cpp_regex_traits.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/regex.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/cregex.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/usinstances.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/fileiter.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/regex_debug.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/c_regex_traits.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/posix_api.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/static_mutex.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/regex_traits_defaults.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/icu.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/codecvt_error_category.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/portability.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/path_traits.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/windows_file_codecvt.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp.o
[ 68%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/unique_path.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/system/src/error_code.cpp.o
[ 71%] Linking CXX static library libBoostParts.a
[ 71%] Built target BoostParts
Scanning dependencies of target ycm_core
[ 72%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CandidateRepository.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/LetterNodeListMap.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierUtils.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Candidate.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/LetterNode.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Result.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/ClangUtils.cpp.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/ClangHelpers.cpp.o
[ 84%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/Range.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/CompletionData.cpp.o
[ 86%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/TranslationUnit.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/CompilationDatabase.cpp.o
[ 89%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/TranslationUnitStore.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/Documentation.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/ClangCompleter.cpp.o
[ 93%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierDatabase.cpp.o
[ 96%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Utils.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/versioning.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library /home/m/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.so
[100%] Built target ycm_core
```

when I finish build the YCM， and config .vimrc ， the code complete function did not work for c file or cpp file~~~

does  anybody know why？

Comment: What plugin manager are you using? Vundle?

Comment: @muru is that need to install plugin manager first ?  I have not install any plugin manager ~~~

Comment: Usually a plugin manager tells Vim to load YCM, or you'd have to manually add `set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe` to your `.vimrc`.

Comment: @muru thanks for your help. YCM is work now after add this words in the .vimrc ! so this words is same with the plugin manager ,is that ?

Comment: The plugin manager makes a bunch of things simpler, including adding to `runtimepath`, updating the plugin, etc.

Comment: @muru OK ,thanks , I always think that plugin manager just one of the way to install YCM,  because I was build YCM from another ways which is to git clone YCM .  so I have forgot to add runtimepath ~~